# Given "tableA Left Join tableB where tableB.col2=1" but col2 could be Null, so how to deal with it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
create tableA (
    idA int primary key,
    idB foreign key references tableB(idB)
);

create tableB (
    idB int primary key,
    type int Not Null
);
```

```
TableA
idA - idB
---------
1   - 2

TableB
idB - type
----------
1   - 1
3   - 3
```

Then, **sql1**

```
select * from tableA a left join tableB b on a.idB=b.idB where b.type=1 // shows no result
```

**sql2**

```
select * from tableA a left join (select * from tableB where type=1) b on a.idB=b.idB // shows 1 result
```

But many people said the 2nd one is not a good practice & they recommend to use `WHere at the end of the statement`, but it could have the `NULL` problem as in sql1

So how to use Where at the end of statement and can handle the NULL issue in LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 3):

You've got to include this condition in the ON clause of your outer join:

```
select * 
from tableA a 
left join tableB b 
on a.idB=b.idB AND b.type=1
```

If you use the condition on the joined table in the WHERE clause, you will change your OUTER JOIN implicitly to an INNER JOIN.